# Kafka brokers - possible to use different ports with Confluent Operator?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I am implementing kafka on kubernetes following the installation steps here: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kubernetes-examples/tree/master/networking/external-access-load-balancer-deploy

I would like to use the same IP address for external access, but specify different ports for each broker.  Is that possible?

```
kafka-0-lb
kafka-1-lb
kafka-2-lb
kafka-bootstrap-lb
```

Basically, I want these 4 components to have same external IP address, but with different ports.

Something like this:

```
kafka-0-lb 100.60.0.10:9097
kafka-1-lb 100.60.0.10:9098
kafka-2-lb 100.60.0.10:9099
kafka-bootstrap-lb 100.60.0.10:9092
```

Comment: Using the opertator, no, I don't think this is possible. Why do you need different ports, anyway?